# How to number_to_currency precision in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, numbers, decimal

When I convert any number through number_to_currency it show only two zeros after dot. I want that if number is 1.000 then three zeros should  and if number 1.00 then two zeros show.

I want if number is 1.0 then after precision 1t becomes 1.00 , I want it remains 1.0. If number is 1.000 it become 1.00 after precision, i want it remins 1.000

Is it possible?

Comment: Your second sentence is unclear: "I want that if number is 1.000 then three zeros should and if number 1.00 then two zeros show." What do you mean by this? Can you edit your question to include some examples of input and the output you want? Have you tried the `:precision` option, [as mentioned in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency)?

Comment: In the floating point world, 1.0, 1.00, 1.000 are all identical. What numbers are you formatting? Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: your question is about `number_to_currency` currency will have 2 trailing zeros because that is currency formatting if you just want to add a dollar sign then just do that instead. `"$#{number}"`. @tadman I think is a bad example and rather he is talking about numbers like 1.1, 1.01, and 1.001

Comment: @engineersmnky 1.001 is often represented internally as something like 1.00099999999938238 so that's not going to work either.

Comment: @haseeb Are these numbers or strings? If they're numbers there is **no difference** between 1.0 and 1.00 or 1.0000000000000. The numbers after the decimal place are only displayed if necessary as a convenience for humans. The computer does not care. There is a [`precision` option for `number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) but you must specify it in advance.

Comment: possible use case: gasoline prices where they show the tenth of pennies as well. so 3.399, for example. I scratched my head at this for a few moments, stuck firmly on the 'why'

Comment: @tadman yes float would be a bad choice for sure preferably integer money in pennies or BigDecimal implementation for sure my point was more advocating for the OP that may his examples were poor and he was not talking about truey equivalent numbers.

Comment: @engineersmnky Absolutely, you need to use a fixed-place representation or you're in trouble in a hurry. I haven't seen systems with variable BigDecimal precision in the database, though, that's usually impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for [Using a dynamic precision value in number_to_currency based on the decimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320051/using-a-dynamic-precision-value-in-number-to-currency-based-on-the-decimal-value)

You'll need to modify the method to return dynamic precision values and also use bigdecimals instead of floats

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
sprintf('%.3f', 1.00)
# => "1.000"
```

It would help you